# Swift evaluate JavaScript in webview

Tags: javascript, html, swift, webview

Why, when I change this function variable "endc" to normal text example

```
let endc = "here is path as string"
```

then is working - when I want to get "path" from function then my code is broken

there is my problem - why?

[image]

Comment: Please post code instead of pictures of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded for `String` class, so both the operand must be `String` for it to work.

Here your variable `endc` is type of `URL`. So the `+` doesn't work for `String` and `URL`.

Better to convert your `URL` into string and then use `+`, like this:

```
var welcome = js + endc.absoluteString + typer
```

Now, it should work.

Also, I think you should add your semicolon in the `typer` string itself.